# How to do a loop with specific (irregular) steps in C?

Tags: c, for-loop

I wrote the following function in C for a greedy algorithm (‘change‘ and 'numberCoins' are global variables).

```
int calculateNumber(void)
{
    numberCoins += change / 25;
    change = change % 25;

    numberCoins += change / 10;
    change = change % 10;

    numberCoins += change / 5;
    change = change % 5;

    numberCoins += change / 1;
    change = change % 1;

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine. However, the copy and paste disturbs me. Is there a possibility to write that without as much repetition? My idea was to write it in a loop. But I couldn't find out how to do a loop with irregular steps. My idea looked like this (how do I make it, that i gets assigned 25 in the first itiration, then 15, then 10 and then 1)?

```
for (int i = 25; i >= 5; ???)
    {
        numberCoins += change / i;
        change = change % i;
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, you can have an array of coins such as `int coin[4] = { 25, 10, 5, 1 };` and iterate 4 times.

Comment: Thank you @WeatherVane. I will make this an answer. Works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @WeatherVane's tip I could find a solution:

```
int calculateNumber(void)
{
    int coins[] = {25, 10, 5, 1};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        numberCoins += change / coins[i];
        change = change % coins[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int nominals[] = {100, 25, 10, 5, 1, 0};

void getNominals(double money, int *result)
{
    unsigned ncents = money * 100.0;
    int *nm = nominals;
    while(*nm && ncents)
    {
        *result++ = ncents / *nm;
        ncents %= *nm++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int result[sizeof(nominals) / sizeof(nominals[0])] = {0};

    getNominals(4.36, result);

    for(size_t index = 0; nominals[index]; index++)
    {
        printf("%d = %d\n", nominals[index], result[index]);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/87c8d7